# expresso-store : add item to order backend doesn't decrease stock

Tags: expresso-store

Hi I'm just wondering if this is a bug or not. When you add an item with inventory to an order in the admin panel, the stock does not reduce, which I believe it should. We have to go back into the product and manually reduce the stock qty.

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed sound like a bug.

Bug reports are best sent directly to the developer along with the version of Store you are using and the version of EE and any steps that you need to recreate the issue.

You can contact DevDemon by either email (support@exp-resso.com) or by the support [form](http://www.devdemon.com/support/form/).

Comment: Thx! I will do just that. Thought it was maybe me.